# what is the most suitable software to take over computers on the net?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I have two computer at home one mine (Admin) and the other belongs to my sister I need some software to take over her computer and support it. I also want to teach her to support by herself the computer so i need her to see what I'm doing.
what is the best\most suitable software for this?

Answer (score 5):

UltraVNC is a great app: http://www.uvnc.com/

Comment: +1 for ultra, great implementation of vnc

Answer (score 4):

get a free [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/US/home.aspx) account its simply, free and works really well and best of all it doesnt require any firewall configuration so you should be able to talk your sister through the setup over the phone and then log in remotely etc

Comment: +1. I use this for friends and family and it works pretty well. Easy to use, free, nothing to configure, I can see what they're doing and vice versa. It saves me the road trip to Aunt Martha's house when she's having email trouble. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are only doing it every now and then, check out [Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/). Not software installs and really easy to get setup. Takes about 4 clicks on even the most restrictive vista uac crappness and I've yet to come across anyone who couldn't get it setup.

Answer (score 1):

[CoPilot by FogCreek Software](https://www.copilot.com/) is based on VNC and acts as a middleman to perform the magic needed to get through NATs and such.  $5/24 hours or per month or per minute costs.

Answer (score 0):

[Ultravnc SC](http://www.uvnc.com/pchelpware/sc/index.html) runs whitout the need to install something. Just forward your ports on your firewall and you're done.

> UltraVNC SC does not require
>   installation and does not make use of
>   the registry. The customer only have
>   to download the little executable and
>   Click to make a connection. The
>   connection is initiated by the server,
>   to allow easy access thru customers
>   firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx). It's free and works great. Works with Windows (including Win7) and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Yest TeamViewer is grat!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remote assistance is built into windows, just have them go to remote assistance and type in your email. It's on the programs menu, in the windows help (F1) and built into windows messenger.

However home routers with built in firewalls make this feature complicated.